# How do you denote the statements $(*)$ and $(**)$ using set notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that if $a$ is an element of the set $A$ then this is denoted as $a\in A$. This is for all elements $a$ and for all sets $A$. If, however, $a$ is not an element of $A$, then this is denoted as $a\notin A$. The same applies if a set $B$ is contained within $A$, denoted as $B\subset A$ or $A\supset B$. And if the contrary, then $B\not\subset A$ or $A\not\supset B$.

If we have the set of elements $\{x, y, z\}$ that are common to both $A$ and $B$, then this is denoted as $\{x, y, z\} = A\cap B$. If the contrary, then this is denoted as $A\Delta B$. If we want to combine both sets together to form a new set $C$ with all of its elements either members of $A$ or $B$, then this is denoted as $C = A\cup B$.

What if $(*)$ $A$ had $n$ elements and $m$ of its elements were also in $B$ for some $0 < m < n$ then how do we write this? How would we write $(**)$ the contrary? By $(**)$, I mean how to denote if $A$ had $n$ elements and $m$ of its elements were *not* in $B$. I know that if $m = n$ then $(*)$ is denoted as $A = B$ or $A\leftrightarrow B$ or $A\subset B$ depending on the value of $m$, what elements are in $A$ and $B$, and how many elements are in $B$. If on the other hand $m = 0$, then this is denoted as $A\cap B = \varnothing =$ the empty (null) set. This makes $A$ and $B$ disjoint sets.

But if $0<m<n$ then how do we denote $(*)$ and $(**)$ using set notation? Would we just write $\{\ldots\} \subset B$ of some sort? I am not aware of a possible duplicate of this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I am talking about there being $m$ elements that are *not* in $B$ as opposed to otherwise; the former.

Comment: It is best to state what you mean ($m$ elements of $A$ that are *not* in $B$) in the body of the Question.  Few Readers can guess that is what you have in mind by "the contrary".

Comment: @hardmath yes I noticed, but the problem has been solved anyway. Sorry about that if you were misunderstood.

Comment: @hardmath I don’t mean to feel so entitled. I do appreciate this. I am grateful that something like the math.SE even exists. I will contribute to the good content, ok. But I just see no point because we have already got the question *answered*. I have already clarified this and that is good enough isn’t it? What’s wrong with it? How is it still a problem? Is there still a misunderstanding?? I ticked the answer because it answered my question. It stated what I meant correctly, apart from the **edit:** part. That was it! I didn’t mean to *offend* anyone. I never had anything against you.

Comment: I just edited the question for the better and now I have a downvote.... I mean, I don’t care about the reputation. I am just curious to know why?

Comment: What I'm saying is that although on one hand you get the benefit of having your Question answered promptly, you have a *responsibility* to edit your Question to make the problem clear.  Hopefully after being involved with Math.SE so much, you have no reluctance to keep your end of the bargain.

Comment: @hardmath but the problem has already been *cleared up*. I clarified it. And I have now even edited the question! I asked this *yesterday*, so why is it *still* a problem today? The answer to the question is below.

Comment: I have removed my downvote (cast before your Edit, because you said it was unnecessary).  The timestamps on the Comments give a good idea of the order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*) $A$ has $n$ elements and $m<n$ of them are in $B$: $|A\cap B| = m$.

(**) $A$ has $n$ elements and $m<n$ of them are NOT in $B$: $|A\setminus B| = m$.

If you meant something else by "the contrary", please let me know!

**EDIT:** If, by "the contrary", you meant that $m<n$ elements of $A$ are in $A\Delta B$, then $|A\Delta B| \geq m$. You can write $A\setminus B \subset A\Delta B$ with $|A\setminus B| = m$. Or, if you mean that there are $m$ elements total in $A\Delta B$, this can obviously be written $|A\Delta B| = m$.

Comment: With *the contrary* I meant that the $m$ elements are not in $B$ as opposed to otherwise, which is what you mentioned anyway. Sorry if I wasn’t clear, but thank you very much :)